# Join multiple XML elements to one java object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to join some xml elements to a java object (using JAXB)?

The following xml is given (out of my controll):

```
<root>
   <user>      
       <user_name>John</user_name>
       <user_lastname>Doe</user_lastname>
       <org_name>ABC</org_name>
       <org_street>Street 123</user_street>
   </user>
</root>
```

Desired result:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class FileXML{

   @XmlElement(name = "user")
   private List<User> users;

}

public class User{
   @XmlElement(name = "user_name")
   private String name;
   @XmlElement(name = "user_lastname")
   private String lastname;
   // ???
   private Org org;
}

public class Org{
   @XmlElement(name = "org_name")
   private String name;
   @XmlElement(name = "org_street")
   private String street;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an existing JAXB annotation for what you are asking. There is custom annotations from custom libraries but I guess you want to stay with JAXB standard.

You could try this code (not tested) :

```
public class User{
   ...

   @XmlElement(name = "street")
   public String setStreet(String street) {
       this.org.setStreet(street);
   }
}
```

But it's clearly a workaround and not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks Gael. That simple solution solves my problem.